# ie10 wont load css dependency with curl.js css plugin

Tags: internet-explorer-10, curljs

Another problem with IE... as usual.

This one seems to be specific to IE10 and curl.js and its css plugin.

When loading css dependency using

```
curl(['css!path/to/css/file.css'])
```

IE10 completely doesn't do anything, no success or failure callbacks, or just flat out errors, just nothing.
Using the developer console, I've tried the same exact code in IE7 through IE9 mode and they seem to work fine...

I've checked the curl.js github issues and couldn't find mention of this specific issue.

Is this a known issue? Is there a solution?

Comment: This issue has been sorted out on github (https://github.com/cujojs/curl/issues/182)... by you ;-)

Comment: yes it was. Thanks for pointing that out, I'd forgotten about it.

Answer (score 0):

It was more of a problem with IE 10's cache not flushing out than curl. Curl has no issues with IE 10 loading css dependency.